# Protractor - How to use variables from a json file in functions

Tags: json, automation, protractor

I'm trying to use variables from a file in a test script, however I'm experiencing an issue `Failed: web.proceedButton.isPresent is not a function`.

My code looks like this:

```
describe('Navigator homepage', function() {
    it('should proceed to login', function() {
        var web = require('../example/webObjectVariables.json');
        web.proceedButton.isPresent();
        web.proceedButton.click();
        web.loginField.sendKeys("login");
        web.passwordField.sendKeys("password");
        web.logInButton.click();

        browser.driver.sleep(1000);
```

Json file looks like this:

```
{
   "proceedButton":"auth-login-page-button",
   "loginField":"login_username",
   "passwordField":"login_password",
   "logInButton":"auth-login-page-button"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can paste the json here?

Comment: Added json file contents.

Comment: are the locator values in css ?

Comment: Those are IDs and not CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`web.proceedButton` is a `"auth-login-page-button"` string which does not have `isPresent()` or `click()` or other methods that protractor's `ElementFinder` has.

I think you forgot to actually locate the element using this locator, assuming `auth-login-page-button` is an id:

```
var loginPageButton = element(by.id(web.proceedButton));
loginPageButton.click();
```

---

Note that a line like `loginPageButton.isPresent()` would not do anything by itself, did you mean to wait for the presence of the button?

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(loginPageButton), 5000);

loginPageButton.click();
```

Comment: I was doing this before within one file. Assigning value to a variable like: `const proceedButton = element(by.id('auth-login-page-button'));` and then using it as `proceedButton.click()`. Then I wanted to remove them from the script and store them in a file with the rest web objects to make them global. Didn't know I have to assign that value to another variable in test to make it accessible. Is it the only way to do that?

Comment: @Qucu generally speaking, a common way to organize tests in a modular way - separating test logic and element locators would be to use [Page Objects](http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects).

Comment: This way seems messy if there is a lot of steps in a test suite and if another test uses a particular object, it needs to be assigned again instead of accessing it from a file. Anyway thank you for clearing things up.